# jquery height in chrome zero

Tags: jquery

I attach capty to images, I do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.shop_banner img').capty({height:150});
});
```

In chrome when I debug capty code `alert($this.height())` is zero so wrapper hide image. I know some browser wants image to be fully loaded but if I use `ready` doesn't mean that it executes after page is fully loaded? What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and ready aren't the same thing.

You can do

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.shop_banner img').capty({height:150});
});
```

[ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) calls your function as soon as the DOM is ready, which doesn't mean images are loaded.

From the documentation :

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the
>   dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a
>   handler for the load event instead.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a load function on an image before doing anything special to it.

```
$(function() {
    $('.shop_banner img').load(function() {
        $(this).capty({height:150});
    });
});
```

Comment: This may not get called if the image was already cached, that is, the load event of the image may fire before the ready event

Comment: I'm curious how that would be possible if the load event is inside a ready function.

Comment: Try this (it failed for me in IE 9) http://jsfiddle.net/HTYTE/4/ (Firefox and Chrome seem to fire an img's load event after the DOM ready even if the image is already cached)

Comment: Is it a problem that you wait for the DOM to be loaded before manipulating an image in javascript?